# how to get click working in redux-react component with enzyme

Tags: react-redux, enzyme, jestjs

Try to test click event to increase a value in the redux state. But the counter value is always 0.

### Counter render

```
render() {
    const { counter, label, isSaving, isLoading, error } = this.props
    return <form>
        <legend>{label}</legend>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify({ counter, isSaving, isLoading }, null, 2)}</pre>
        <button ref='increment' onClick={this._onClickIncrement}>click me!</button>
        <button ref='save' disabled={isSaving} onClick={this._onClickSave}>{isSaving ? 'saving...' : 'save'}</button>
        <button ref='load' disabled={isLoading} onClick={this._onClickLoad}>{isLoading ? 'loading...' : 'load'}</button>
        {error ? <div className='error'>{error}</div> : null}
    </form>
}
```

### Jest Test

```
let container, store
beforeEach(() => {
  store = mockStore(initialState)
  container = shallow(<Counter label='a counter!' store={store} />)
})
it('+++ check Props after increments counter', () => {
  const mockClick = jasmine.createSpy('click');
  expect(container.find('button').at(0).type()).toEqual('button');
  const increment = container.find('button').at(0)
  container.find('button').at(0).simulate('click')
  container.find('button').at(0).simulate('click')
  container.find('button').at(0).simulate('click')

  const pre = container.find('pre');
  // const pre = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(counter, 'pre')
  console.log(container.props().counter);

  // expect(JSON.parse(counter.find('pre').first.text()).counter.value).toEqual(3)
})
```

Comment: Please, share your complete component code and your reducer.

Comment: I would just reduce complexity by only testing the unwrapped component and pass the redux handler props as a spy into the component.